# Pandas Series.filter.values returning different type than numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy

I am trying to run the `scipy.stats.entropy` function on two arrays. It is being run on each row of a Pandas DataFrame via the apply function:

```
def calculate_H(row):
    pk = np.histogram(row.filter(regex='stuff'), bins=16)[0]
    qk = row.filter(regex='other').values
    stats.entropy(pk, qk, base=2)

df['DKL'] = df.apply(calculate_H, axis=1)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'xlogy' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

(I've also tried `qk = row[row.filter(regex='other').index].values`)

I know the issue is with the `qk`, I can pass another array as `qk` and it works. The issue is that Pandas is giving me something that says it is a numpy array but it is not quite a numpy array. The following examples all work:

```
qk1 = np.array([12024, 9643, 7681, 8193, 8012, 7846, 7615, 7484, 5966, 11484, 13627, 17749, 9820, 5336,4611, 3366])
qk2 = Series([12024, 9643, 7681, 8193, 8012, 7846, 7615, 7484, 5966, 11484, 13627, 17749, 9820, 5336,4611, 3366]).values
qk3 = df.filter(regex='other').iloc[0].values
```

If I check the types, e.g. `type(qk) == type(qk1)` it gives me True (all `numpy.ndarray`). Or if I use `np.array_equals`, also True.

The ONLY hint I have is what happens when I print out the arrays that work vs don't (not working on bottom):

```
[12024  9643  7681  8193  8012  7846  7615  7484  5966 11484 13627 17749  9820  5336  4611  3366]
[12024 9643 7681 8193 8012 7846 7615 7484 5966 11484 13627 17749 9820 5336 4611 3366]
```

Notice the one on top has larger spacing in between values.

**TLDR**; These two expressions return something different

```
df.filter(regex='other').iloc[0].values
df.iloc[0].filter(regex='other').values
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect `qk` is an `object` array and not an array of integers.  In `calculate_H`, try this:

```
qk = row.filter(regex='other').values.astype(int)
```

(i.e. cast the values to an array of integers).

Comment: Ah yes! That fixed it. Why would it change the type of items in the array? Before I do the filter it is an array of integers.

Comment: I'm don't know where or why the `object` array first appears--I'm not a heavy user of pandas.  You could add a bunch of `print` statements to your code, and carefully check the data types of the pandas objects each time you create a new one.

Comment: Turns out if any column in the original dataframe is an object, the series created via apply is of object type. Thanks again. https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8009#issuecomment-52043645